# Convert.ToDecimal throws exception for simple string

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to convert string "10.00" to decimal like this:

```
decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal("10.00");
```

But for some unbelievable reason I get this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) at System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value) at Presentation.Models.OrderBaseModel.Response(FormCollection response, String responseUrl)

Is there any deeper reason? How can "10.00" string be unparsable??

Comment: It's probably a culture issue - did you try parsing "10,00"?

Answer (score 5):

Convert.ToDecimal() calls Decimal.Parse()

To ensure 10.00 will parse you need to use a culture that will parse it.

```
var culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
decimal a = Decimal.Parse("10.00",culture);
```

Comment: It still can throw, because `CreateSpecificCulture` use user overrides from control panel, and user can override decimal separator. It better to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead.